# How to use fastlane on physical ios devices?

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

Right now i am running:

```
fastlane scan --scheme MyUITests \
--destination 'platform=iOS,id=myId' \
--destination 'platform=iOS,id=myId2' \ 
--output_types "junit" --output_files "report.xml" --clean
```

This runs the tests on the second device (myId2) but not the first one. If I switch the order, then (myId) would run and (myId2) would not. So it takes the last `--destination`. I was wondering how I could run tests on multiple connected devices.

When I tried using a fastfile:

```
lane :uitests do
  scan(devices: ["asd's iPhone", "asd's iPad"],
       scheme: "MyUITests",
        output_types: "junit",
        output_files: "report.xml",
        clean: true)
end
```

It won't recognize the name. I tried the uuids but they didn't work either. I get the following error:

```
[13:08:40]: Ignoring 'blah's iPhone', couldn’t find matching simulator
[13:08:40]: Ignoring 'asg's iPad', couldn’t find matching simulator
[13:08:40]: Couldn't find any matching simulators for '["blah's iPhone", "asg's iPad"]' - falling back to default simulator
[13:08:40]: Found simulator "iPhone 5s (11.4)"
```

So how do I test on multiple connected devices at once?

I don't want to use a simulator because I need to test on cellular and do other things that can only be done with a physical device. I tried xcodebuild but it did not generate junit xml reports, I need those for jenkins and fastlane does it for one device when I am doing it right now.

Comment: Have you got any answer for this. am also facing the same as you

Answer (score 0):

I've been successfully running scan on a physical device. You can use destination with platform and id to specify a platform of iOS and a device UDID for id

i.e. -destination 'platform=iOS,id=UDUD' where UDID is a valid device UDID

Comment: That is what I said I was doing in my post. It works perfectly for one device, but I want to know how to do it with more than 1 device. It only runs 1 device even if i put 2 destinations.